# .NET MVC Core handling form inside for loop with jquery/ajax - only returning first selection

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I might be close, but can't seem to figure out what is missing in this case. I have a view that creates a form inside the questions for loop, and then the only field that has to be selected is from the radio button list generated by the answers for loop.

I am using jquery/ajax to post so that the page doesn't redirect on every submit. My code is working in that every time I click the saveLink button it creates a new record in the database. The problem is that when I select an answer for the first question, it saves the selectedquestionid and selectedanswerid of that question and answer, but when I move to the next question and select an answer, it saves the ids from the first question and answer again.

I need it to save the correct ids. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

View (simplified for brevity)

```
@for int(i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
{
   <form asp-action="Save" id="myForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TestName)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedQuestionID, Model.Questions[i].ID)

          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Questions[i].QuestionText)
          @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Answers.Count; j++)
          {
               <div>
                   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedAnswerID, Model.Questions[i].Answer[j].ID)@Html.Label("", Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].AnswerText)
               </div>
          }
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="button" class="saveLink" value="Save" />
      </div>
   </form>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.saveLink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault;

        $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr("href"),
            type:'POST',
            data:$('#myForm').serialize(),
            success:function(){
                alert("Saved");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public void Save(RespVM respVM)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var qid = _context.Answer.Where(a => a.ID == respVM.SelectedAnswerID).Select(a => a.QuestionID).FirstOrDefault();

      var RespModel = new Resp
      {
          SelectedQuestionID = qid,
          SelectedAnswerID = respVM.SelectedAnswerID,
          TestName = respVM.TestName,
      }

      _context.Add(RespModel);
      _context.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Comment: Maybe with something like `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedAnswerID, Model.Questions[i].Answer[j].ID, new { @id = Model.Questions[i].Answer[j].ID})`

Comment: The value of respVM.SelectedAnswerID gets passed in from the radiobuttonlist on submit. The value of qid is then calculated based off that value to get the correct questionid for that answer. The value of respVM.TestName gets passed from the hiddenfield which gets it's value from the viewmodel. The viewmodel combines test, question, and answer models.

Comment: it seems your posted data contains all the answers instead of posting single question and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$('#myForm').serialize(),
```

You serialize the 1st object with an `id="myForm"`

In your loop, you give all your forms the same id, so that's why it returns the 1st form everytime

```
<form asp-action="Save" id="myForm">
```

Instead of giving them and id, you should give them a class, and then refer to them from the clicked button. Something like that :

```
<form asp-action="Save" class="myForm">
$(this).closest('.myForm').serialize()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed, it's working perfectly now. And I really appreciate the explanation, I am still trying to learn how to use jquery/ajax so that helps me immensely moving forward to understand.